# Looping over pairs of files

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

Hello I need to iterate over pairs of files and do something with them.

For example I have 4 files which are named `AA2234_1.fastq.gz` `AA2234_2.fastq.gz` `AA3945_1.fastq.gz` `AA3945_2.fastq.gz`

As you can propably tell the pairs are `AA2234_1.fastq.gz` <-> `AA2234_2.fastq.gz` and `AA3945_1.fastq.gz` <-> `AA3945_2.fastq.gz` (they share the name before `_` sign)

I have a `command` with syntax looking like this:

`initialize_of_command file1 file2 output_a output_b output_c output_d parameteres`

I want this script to find the number of files with `fastq.gz` extension in a directory, divide them by 2 to find number of pairs then match the pairs together using probably regex (maybe to two variables) and execute this `command` for each pair once.

I have no idea how to pair up those files using regex and how to iterate over the pairs so the scripts knows through which pairs it have already iterated.

Here is my unfinished script:

```
#!/bin/bash
raw_count_of_files=$(ls | grep -c "fastq.gz")
count_of_files=$((raw_count_of_files / 2))

for ((i=1;i<=count_of_files;i++));
do
java -jar /home/aa/git/trimmomatic/src/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -phred33 AA2234_1.fastq.gz AA2234_2.fastq.gz AA2234_forward_paired.fq.gz AA2234_forward_unpaired.fq.gz AA2234_reverse_paired.fq.gz AA2234_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:20;
done
```

Also I would like for the output names to be named after the shared name of input files which in this case is `AA2234` and `AA3945`

The desired output of this script should be 8 files named accordingly to pairs:

```
AA2234_forward_paired.fq.gz 
AA2234_forward_unpaired.fq.gz 
AA2234_reverse_paired.fq.gz 
AA2234_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz
```

and

```
AA3945_forward_paired.fq.gz 
AA3945_forward_unpaired.fq.gz 
AA3945_reverse_paired.fq.gz 
AA3945_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz
```

Comment: I'm positive you can coax a shell to do this, but I'm always amazed that people bother. The arcane, unintuitive, and error prone semantics of bash are just too painful. Imo you're more likely to get a correct result and get it quicker with a more general purpose language like Python. In a previous decade, you'd use Perl, which was invented for stuff like this.

Comment: Anyway, even in bash if the pairs always differ in only some digits following the underscore before `.fastq`, this won't be hard.  You can build two arrays with glob patterns and then iterate through pairs  using the pattern shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413976/how-to-shift-array-value-in-bash . You haven't specified the situation in enough detail to give a full answer.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't use Python to do it. It would be a lot easier. I have no idea how to specify it more. Thank you for the comment I will look into that

Comment: Needs explanation on how you get paired and unpaired.

Comment: paired and unpaired is just a name of output file. The output of the command that i use just makes paired and unpaired files (its genetics so I won't go into detail with it)

Comment: This can be easiy done using an assoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the filenames do not contain whitespace, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash                         # associative array to tie basename with files
for f in *fastq.gz; do                  # search the files with the suffix
    base=${f%_*}                        # remove after "_"
    if [[ -z ${hash[$base]} ]]; then    # if the variable is not defined
        hash[$base]=$f                  # then store the filename
    else
        hash[$base]+=" $f"              # else append the filenmame delimited by the whitespace
    fi
done

for base in "${!hash[@]}"; do           # loop over the hash keys (basename)
    read -r f1 f2 <<< "${hash[$base]}"  # split into filenames

    echo java -jar /home/aa/git/trimmomatic/src/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -phred33 "$f1" "$f2" "$base"_forward_paired.fq.gz "$base"_forward_unpaired.fq.gz "$base"_reverse_paired.fq.gz "$base"_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:20;
done
```

The script outputs the java command lines as a dry run. If the output looks good, drop `echo` and run.

Answer (score 2):

One way to iterate over pairs of arguments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

proc_fastq_pairs() {
  # loop while there are fastq files passed as argument
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    fq1=$1
    # consume 1 argument as file 1
    shift
    fq2=$1
    # consume 1 argument as file 2
    shift
    initialize_of_command "$fq1" "$fq2" output_a output_b output_c output_d parameteres
  done
}

initialize_of_command() {
  # dummy command to show passed arguments for debug purpose
  printf 'initialize_of_command %s\n' "$*"
}

# Expansion of the globbing pattern ./*.fastq.gz
# is always sorted alphabetically.
# It ensures all similarly named files are kept
# togaether fq1 fq2 ...
proc_fastq_pairs ./*.fastq.gz
```

Alternatively with `xargs`:

```sh
printf '%s\n' ./*.fastq.gz | xargs -L 2 bash -c 'initialize_of_command "$1" "$2" output_a output_b output_c output_d parameteres' _
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A assoc=()
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *_?.fastq.gz; do
    base=${f%_*}
    assoc[$base]=${assoc[$base]-}${assoc[$base]+ }$f
done

set -f

for pair in "${assoc[@]}"; do
    set -- $pair
    # TODO: Check $# and do something with $1 and $2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are exactly two files for each prefix (prefix is the portion before the `_` in filename), then this job could be accomplished by using a simple `for` without resorting to arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

jarfile='/home/aa/git/trimmomatic/src/Trimmomatic/trimmomatic-0.39.jar'

prefix=
for file in *_*.fastq.gz; do
    if [[ $prefix ]]; then
        echo java -jar "$jarfile" PE -phred33 \
            "$first" "$file" "$prefix"_{forward,reverse}_{,un}paired.fq.gz \
            'SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20' 'MINLEN:20'
        prefix=
    else
        first=$file
        prefix=${file%%_*}
    fi
done
```

Drop the `echo` if the command printed out looks good.